# Upload image to API using Flutter and Dio

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

How can I send image to API in string format? This is the code where the data is sent in MultipartFile instance but `data['avatar']` accepts string. So how can I do it? Please help me with this.

```
static Future<Response> updateUserAccount({
    XFile? avatar,
    String? fullName,
    String? email,
    String? oldPhone,
    String? phone,
    String? city,
    String? streetName,
    String? landmark,
    String? oldPassword,
    String? password,
  }) async {
    final dio = Dio();
    String token = await SecureStorageUtils.getToken();
    dio.options.headers['accept'] = '*/*';
    dio.options.headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    dio.options.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    if (avatar != null) {
      data['avatar'] = await MultipartFile.fromFile(avatar.path);
    }

    if (email != null) {
      data['email'] = email;
    }

    if (oldPhone != null) {
      data['old_phone_number'] = oldPhone;
    }

    if (phone != null) {
      data['phone_number'] = phone;
    }

    if (city != null || streetName != null || landmark != null) {
      final address = {};

      if (city != null) {
        address['city'] = city;
      }

      if (streetName != null) {
        address['street_name'] = streetName;
      }

      if (landmark != null) {
        address['landmark'] = landmark;
      }
      data['address'] = address;
    }

    if (oldPassword != null) {
      data['old_password'] = oldPassword;
    }
    if (password != null) {
      data['password'] = password;
    }
    if (fullName != null) {
      data['full_name'] = fullName;
    }
    print("data: $data");

    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(data);

    final response = await dio.patch(
      AppUrl.currentUser,
      data: formData,
    );
    return response;
  }
```

I tried this way using base64Encoding but it did not work.

```
List<int> fileBytes = await avatar.readAsBytes();
  String base64Avatar = base64Encode(fileBytes);
  data['avatar'] = base64Avatar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my case is that i can send json data as the data is string file so i created a class that create base64 e.g.

```
class ToImageData {
  static String imagetoData(String? imagepath) {
    final extension = path.extension(
      imagepath!.substring(imagepath.lastIndexOf("/")).replaceAll("/", ""),
    );
    final bytes = File(imagepath).readAsBytesSync();
    String base64 =
        "data:image/${extension.replaceAll(".", "")};base64,${base64Encode(bytes)}";
    return base64;
  }
}
```

so whenever i have to send file in json for i call it like this

```
 // Lets make an example
 final data = {
     "avatar": ToImageData.imagetoData(file.path);
     // result is like this data:image/png;base64,TEWUFDBSJWEH1232347GHSD
    //something long text
 }

final response = await dio.patch(
      AppUrl.currentUser,
      data: data ,
    );
    return response;
```

I hope this finds you helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For this I have used [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image)

import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

```
File? _image; //Your image-file variable

_image = File(pickedFile.path); //Once user picked image file.

//Upload to API

 var fileName;
 if (_image != null) {
    fileName = _image!.path.split('/').last;
  }
 final capturedImage = img.decodeImage(await _image!.readAsBytes())!;
    final orientedImage = img.bakeOrientation(capturedImage);
    final thumbnail = img.copyResize(orientedImage, width: 200);
    await _image!.writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(thumbnail)).then((value) async {
     'avatar':
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image!.path, filename: fileName)
      _callSaveProfileApi(formData);
    });
```